# Graphics performance improvement / GDI alternative?

Tags: c#, performance, gdi, slimdx, sharpdx

can anyone suggest any alternative to GDI?
The reason is that I have data that updates rapidly and GDI doesn't support that kind of render velocity... I've tried SharpDX & SlimDX, but none seems to work properly (can't force them to draw on form without errors)

**Update 1:** I'm developing in C#

**Update 2:** Data is binded to Visual Studio 2010 default Charts control. A lot of code has been written to add functionality & lags were discovered after large amount of data incoming. Reason is that I need compatibility with .NET Framework 4 & Windows XP and higher.
After spending a lot of time investigating, I've discovered that SlimDX and SharpDX have strict requirements to videocard, drivers, and problems running on Windows XP.

Comment: Are you sure it's GDI that's the bottleneck, not .net?  How are you calling the GDI functions?

Comment: yes I'm sure because it starts to loose performance only when graphics are involved...

Comment: That's not the same thing.  It could easily be that the .net layer that sits between your code and the Win32 GDI API is the bottleneck.  Have you tried making a small C/C++ example that performs the same GDI operations and tested it to see if it is also slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDI is software only rendering, as well as GDI+ which handles alpha channel for transparency rendering. These two libraries are really limited and slow compared to a GPU based one.

My suggestion is that you should invest the time to implement a SharpDX Direct2D based drawing engine. I never heard about the issue you talked about with forms, I use SharpDX with Winforms and WPF and everything's going great!

If speed is the most important criteria, then you'll have to invest time into a GPU based rendering engine, GDI is way to slow and not adapted to real-time rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I find it strange that GDI doesn't suffice in that context but there are a lot of alternatives: you could go for DirectDraw for complete power, GDI+ for more advanced manipulations and options, or even external softwares like GTK+.